# Python: compress and save/load large data from/into memory

Tags: python, zlib

I have a huge dictionary with numpy arrays as values which consumes almost all RAM. There is no possibility to pickle or compress it entirely. I've checked [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675381/python-compress-large-files) of [solutions](https://gist.github.com/davidcrawford/6774493) to read/write in chunks using `zlib`, but they work with files, `StringIO`, etc, when I want to read/write from/into RAM.

[Here is the closest example to what I want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33563348/1692060), but it has only writing part. How can I read the object after saving this way, because chunks were written together and compressed chunks of course have different length?

```
import zlib


class ZlibWrapper():
    # chunksize is used to save memory, otherwise huge object will be copied
    def __init__(self, filename, chunksize=268435456): # 256 MB
        self.filename = filename
        self.chunksize = chunksize


    def save(self, data): 
        """Saves a compressed object to disk
        """
        mdata = memoryview(data)
        with open(self.filename, 'wb') as f:
          for i in range(0, len(mdata), self.chunksize):
             mychunk = zlib.compress(bytes(mdata[i:i+self.chunksize]))
             f.write(mychunk)

    def load(self):

        # ???

        return data
```

Uncompressed objects unfortunately would be too huge to be sent over network, and zipping them externally would create additional complications.

Pickle unfortunately starts to consume RAM and system hangs.

Following the discussion with Charles Duffy, here is my attempt of serialization (does not work at the moment - does not even compress the strings):

```
import zlib

import json

import numpy as np



mydict = {"a":np.array([1,2,3]),"b":np.array([4,5,6]),"c":np.array([0,0,0])}


#------------


# write to compressed stream ---------------------

def string_stream_serialization(dic):
    for key, val in dic.items():        
        #key_encoded = key.encode("utf-8")  # is not json serializable
        yield json.dumps([key,val.tolist()])


output = ""
compressor = zlib.compressobj()
decompressor = zlib.decompressobj()


stream = string_stream_serialization(mydict)

with open("outfile.compressed", "wb") as f:
    for s in stream:
        if not s:
            f.write(compressor.flush())
            break
        f.write(compressor.compress(s.encode('utf-8'))) # .encode('utf-8') converts to bytes




# read from compressed stream: --------------------

def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024): # I set another chunk size intentionally
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data


reconstructed = {}

with open("outfile.compressed", "rb") as f:
    for s in read_in_chunks(f):
        data = decompressor.decompress(decompressor.unconsumed_tail + s)
        while data:
            arr = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))            
            reconstructed[arr[0]] = np.array(arr[1])
            data = decompressor.decompress(decompressor.unconsumed_tail)


print(reconstructed)
```

Comment: A bunch of concatenated zlib streams is itself usable as a zlib stream, so you don't need to do anything differently based on whether the stream in question was created this way or not.

Comment: What would an ideal interface look like on the load side? You pass in a `memoryview` of the right size and it gets populated? The biggest problem I have with answering this one is more around figuring out what you want than building an implementation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `memoryview` was just my attempt, because I couldn't figure out how to reconstruct dictionary object after that. On the load side I want to read saved compressed file in chunks and reconstruct the huge object I saved (keeping in mind that I operate at the rim of my RAM), for example by casting the resulting buffer into dict or something. Now I wonder if that is possible in python

Comment: There's no question that this is possible; it's just a question of doing the work to write an efficient encoder or decoder for an appropriate format. If you only need an answer that works with dictionaries of numpy arrays (of a specific type? If so, what type?), that's helpful clarification to let a concrete implementation be written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! Yes, I have a dictionary of a type `{string: np.array}`; words in unicode are keys and values are numpy arrays which have the same dimension (let's say, 300. But can contain `np.nan` on some coordinates).

Comment: What's the dtype of those arrays? An actual representative sample of the data you want to serialize or deserialize being added to the question would do a lot of good.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `dtype('float32')  `

Comment: Do `ndarray.tofile()` and `ndarray.fromfile()` work from a memory-usage perspective, if you ignored the need for compression? (If so, we should be able to just hook up some FIFOs to stream said contents through a compressor on one side and a decompressor on the other and call it a day).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I indeed can perform compression/decompression externally if needed. If we work element-wise or in small batches, I think it's ok (I set 256 MB chunk in my example). It's just will cause problems if there will be a few hundreds of megabytes or gigabyte or more of overhead.  I thought myself about saving `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` separately, but I guess that zipping back to dictionary will cause copying objects in RAM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164580/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-slowpoke).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your first focus should be on having a sane way to serialize and deserialize your data.** We have several constraints about your data provided in the question itself, or in comments on same:

- Your data consists of a dictionary with a very large number of key/value pairs
- All keys are unicode strings
- All values are numpy arrays which are individually short enough to easily fit in memory at any given time (or even to allow multiple copies of any single value), although *in aggregate* the storage required becomes extremely large.

This suggests a fairly simple implementation:

```
def serialize(f, content):
    for k,v in content.items():
        # write length of key, followed by key as string
        k_bstr = k.encode('utf-8')
        f.write(struct.pack('L', len(k_bstr)))
        f.write(k_bstr)
        # write length of value, followed by value in numpy.save format
        memfile = io.BytesIO()
        numpy.save(memfile, v)
        f.write(struct.pack('L', memfile.tell()))
        f.write(memfile.getvalue())

def deserialize(f):
    retval = {}
    while True:
        content = f.read(struct.calcsize('L'))
        if not content: break
        k_len = struct.unpack('L', content)[0]
        k_bstr = f.read(k_len)
        k = k_bstr.decode('utf-8')
        v_len = struct.unpack('L', f.read(struct.calcsize('L')))[0]
        v_bytes = io.BytesIO(f.read(v_len))
        v = numpy.load(v_bytes)
        retval[k] = v
    return retval
```

As a simple test:

```
test_file = io.BytesIO()
serialize(test_file, {
    "First Key": numpy.array([123,234,345]),
    "Second Key": numpy.array([321,432,543]),
})

test_file.seek(0)
print(deserialize(test_file))
```

...so, we've got that -- now, how do we add compression? Easily.

```
with gzip.open('filename.gz', 'wb') as gzip_file:
    serialize(gzip_file, your_data)
```

...or, on the decompression side:

```
with gzip.open('filename.gz', 'rb') as gzip_file:
    your_data = deserialize(gzip_file)
```

**This works because the `gzip` library already streams data out as it's requested, rather than compressing it or decompressing it all at once.** There's no need to do windowing and chunking yourself -- just leave it to the lower layer.

Comment: Thanks very much! I haven't seen your answer and posted my own (though not working) attempt.

Answer (score 2):

To write a dictionary to disk, the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html) module is a good fit.

- When saving  - Save each chunk as a file in the zip.
- When loading - Iterate over the files in the zip and rebuild the data.

Comment: This is a completely different compression algorithm and data format than the OP asked for, and for no benefit whatsoever: zlib itself is a format designed with the explicit intent of letting two compressed streams be concatenated and decompressed to yield the same result as concatenating the decompressed contents.

Comment: The question is how to compress data in memory - It is not about zlib

Comment: Still -- the OP actually already has a solution that does what they want; they just misunderstand its semantics in such a way as to *think* they need to take extra care on decoding, when in fact such extra care is unnecessary. To tell them to abandon that solution and go with an inherently random-access, non-streaming-capable approach (zipfile decoding is a footer-based format that can't be streamed as it require `seek()`ing) is foolishness.

Comment: Thanks, that could be indeed one of the solutions, though a bit more messy (sending a folder with many small zip files over network). The only thing that left for me for both of the approaches is to understand how to create and increase buffer until the right size while reading data into it...

Comment: It is not foolishness - It is just another idea.

Comment: @napuzba, ...you're right. I initially read the OP's comment talking about copying content over a network to mean that they intended to transfer data over a socket this way without writing it to disk first (and because the `zip` format expects seeking from indexes, it's not suitable for this use case) -- but looking at the record more closely, this was never an explicit part of the question, which was indeed more general than how I read it to be. Please accept my apologies.